# Install CCP4-7.0 on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

Tags: software-installation, permissions

I am quite new to Ubuntu and try to get things running.

I tried to install CCP4-7.0, but not succesfully.

```
Tom@M0T:~/ccp4-7.0$ BINARY.setup
Setting up paths...
/home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/BINARY.setup: line 38: bin/ccp4.setup-sh: Permission denied
/home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/BINARY.setup: line 41: bin/ccp4.setup-csh: Permission denied
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libgfortran.so.3': Permission denied
/home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/BINARY.setup: line 66: ./bin/ccp4.setup-sh: No such file or directory
./make_examples.sh: 15: ./make_examples.sh: cannot create example1.html: Permission denied
./make_examples.sh: 61: ./make_examples.sh: cannot create index.html: Permission denied
11:10:37 Running auto-configure for configure
Creating new directory /home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/share/ccp4i/etc/unix
You are the first person to run this version of CCP4i and
it is trying to automatically configure and save information
to the file:
/home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/share/ccp4i/etc/unix/configure.def
but you do not have write permission for this directory.
Please get the person who installed CCP4i to run it and
do the configure.
It is OK to continue running CCP4i.
Compiling py-files
Completing cctbx dispatcher install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../site-packages/cctbx_project/libtbx/configure.py", line 22, in <module>
    if not run():
  File "../site-packages/cctbx_project/libtbx/configure.py", line 17, in run
    libtbx.env_config.cold_start(sys.argv)
  File "/home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/lib/py2/site-packages/cctbx_project/libtbx/env_config.py", line 2274, in cold_start
    env = environment(build_path=build_path)
  File "/home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/lib/py2/site-packages/cctbx_project/libtbx/env_config.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.manage_python_version_major_minor()
  File "/home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/lib/py2/site-packages/cctbx_project/libtbx/env_config.py", line 449, in manage_python_version_major_minor
    path.open("w").write("""\
  File "/home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/lib/py2/site-packages/cctbx_project/libtbx/path.py", line 259, in open
    return open(abs(self), *args, **kwds)
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/Tom/ccp4-7.0/lib/py2/cctbx/lib/PYTHON_VERSION_MAJOR_MINOR'
Configuring qtpisa...

         Before running CCP4 programs from command line,
         source bin/ccp4.setup-sh
         (or bin/ccp4.setup-csh if you use csh).
```

I don't how to resolve `Permission denied`

Hope someone can help.

Comment: `Permission denied` errors for files in your home directory usually indicate misuse of `sudo` - for example, using `sudo tar` to unpack an archive

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. For the future I should avoid using 'sudo' if not necessary ...